# Why do I get SQLAlchemy nested rollback error?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got an error as follows in my code of python (which collects twitter statuses and store in database).

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back by a nested rollback() call.  To begin a new transaction, issue Session.rollback() first.
```

I want to know what is the problem, why does it occur, and how can I solve it.

I have no idea about `nested rollback`. Is there any simple example which occurs `nested rollback`?

Comment: Since this hasn't had the answer posted yet, but it's in the question now: the summary is to leverage a try-except block, with your `session.commit()` in the `try` and a `session.rollback()` in cases of exceptions.  @fbessho, you should really post your edit as an answer.

Comment: @bsplosion Thanks for the suggestion. I made the edit part as an answer. Note that I also changed the question title as the original "SQLAlchemy Nested rollback error" doesn't meet stack overflow's current requirement.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem was solved.
The point, in this case, is that rollback is not executed until we call rollback explicitly, so when we include `commit()`, we should write it in a try statement, and write `rollback()` in the exception statement (in most case) as written in https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/sessions.html#this-session-s-transaction-has-been-rolled-back-due-to-a-previous-exception-during-flush-or-similar

And, here is the correct code example. I quoted this from the link above.

```
try:
    <use session>
    session.commit()
except:
    session.rollback()
    raise
finally:
    session.close()  # optional, depends on use case
```

Comment: not working with this code , i still getting the same error

Comment: i had to remove the db and let flask to generate it again, by then it worked

Answer (score 3):

As identified by @fbessho above, this is indeed the correct pattern:

```
try:
    <use session>
    session.commit()
except:
    session.rollback()
```

However, there are some subtleties that can derail the error handling.

In this example (an imaginary unique constraint violation), the rollback does not occur:

```
class Thing1(Base):
   id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)


class Thing2(Base):
   id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)


def do_something(s: session, thing_1: Thing1, duplicate_id):

   # imagine this violates a unique constraint on Thing2
   thing_2 = Thing2(id=duplicate_id)
   s.add(thing_2)

   try:
       # the exception will occur when the commit statement is executed
       s.commit()
   except Exception as ex:
       # this will log details of the exception
       logger.error(f"{ex.__class__.__name__}: {ex}")
       # referencing thing_1.id will raise a second exception
       logger.error(f"Commit failed.  Thing1 id was {thing_1.id}.")
       s.rollback()
```

This second Exception occurs even though thing_1 has nothing to do with the failed insert.  Merely referencing thing_1 raises a second Exception which prevents the rollback from being executed.

**Solution 1**

This requires a little more overhead, but will always work.

```
def do_something_1(s: session, thing_1: Thing1, duplicate_id):

   # create a reference that does not rely on the data object
   id_for_thing = thing_1.id

   # imagine this violates a unique constraint on Thing2
   thing_2 = Thing2(id=duplicate_id)
   s.add(thing_2)

   try:
       # the exception will occur when the commit statement is executed
       s.commit()
   except Exception as ex:
       logger.error(f"{ex.__class__.__name__}: {ex}")
       # no direct reference to thing_1
       logger.error(f"Commit failed.  Thing1 id was {id_for_thing}.")
       s.rollback()
```

**Solution 2**

This will work as long as thing_1 is not affected by the rollback.

```
def do_something_2(s: session, thing_1: Thing1, duplicate_id):

   # imagine this violates a unique constraint on Thing2
   thing_2 = Thing2(id=duplicate_id)
   s.add(thing_2)

   try:
       # the exception will occur when the commit statement is executed
       s.commit()
   except Exception as ex:
       logger.error(f"{ex.__class__.__name__}: {ex}")
       s.rollback()
       # thing_1.id can be referenced after rollback
       logger.error(f"Commit failed.  Thing1 id was {thing_1.id}.")
```